# Drupal 6.2: recommended method for internal links?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, forum, image-gallery

Getting familiar with Drupal 6.2 at the moment; plan on migrating a Bitweaver site to Drupal 6.2 (and eventually 7 once the modules catch up).

Our current Bitweaver site has user-created/managed image galleries; we also post articles with embedded locally-stored Flash videos.

I had used/extended a tag system whereas users could cross-post their gallery images into the forums by using special markup (under each image details, the tag was auto-generated with a click event to copy the tag to the clipboard).  This tag system was also extended to the content editors so that they could post articles with videos in a similar manner (basically `{flashvideo file='/file/you/uploaded.flv'}`). This worked well.

For modules, I'm using the Advanced Forums as well as Node Gallery as they seem to be able to accomplish what we need (your typical forum and user galleries with sub-galleries, lightbox, etc.).

However, with the myriad of modules and sub-modules in Drupal, I'm not sure if there's a tag-based system, or even better, an integrated image or video picker in the WYSIWYG editor(s) that would allow:

a) users to browse image objects they own and embed in their forum posts;

b) editors to browse video objects and embed in their articles (content nodes)

Answer (score 2):

For images I would recommend [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) - it integrated awesomely with Ckeditor and also the WYSIWYG API module.

With IMCE you can assign each user their own private folder, and allocate quota etc. There is also a handy resize feature that lets users create thumbnails for embedding in content.

For video, I would recommend either:

- Using the media embed dialog in Ckeditor (which allows YouTube, vimeo etc code to be pasted into the body)
- Using the [video module](http://drupal.org/project/video) - and allowing certain users to create 'video nodes'

Comment: I installed IMCE yesterday and integrated with the CKEditor (WYSIWYG); looks like it works quite well.  Doesn't seem to integrate with Node Gallery though; might have to look elsewhere for user galleries.